# mysql get records order by priority without full text search

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to convert string into words and then using "case" function to generate priority and finally order everything by priority or the amount of matches desc. All works but its very slow and crashes my site. Could you give me some pointers to make it faster?

I can't use match against function case because my server doesn't have it.

Here is my query:

```
select  b.activityActionId,b.creatorFeedId,b.priority
 from
(SELECT DISTINCT activity.actionId as activityActionId, NULL as creatorFeedId, activity.timeStamp, (case when action.data like '%you%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%don%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%see%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%this%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%email%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%your%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%inbox%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%within%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%minutes%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%look%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%for%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%junk%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%mail%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%folder%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%find%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%there%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%please%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%mark%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%the%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%Not%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%Junk%' then 1 else 0 end) as priority
         FROM `activity` activity    
         INNER JOIN action action on action.id = activity.actionId
         WHERE ((case when action.data like '%you%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%don%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%see%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%this%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%email%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%your%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%inbox%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%within%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%minutes%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%look%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%for%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%junk%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%mail%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%folder%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%find%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%there%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%please%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%mark%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%the%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%Not%' then 1 else 0 end)+(case when action.data like '%Junk%' then 1 else 0 end)) > 0 AND action.id != "56"
union
        SELECT NULL as actionId, `actionId`, null as timeStamp, null as priority    
        FROM `activity`             
WHERE `activityType` = "create" and `userId` = "1" and `actionId` != "56"
        ORDER BY `timeStamp` desc
        )b
         ORDER BY priority desc, b.`timeStamp` DESC LIMIT 10
```

I might also consider establishing words limit case it will get out of control on some really log content.

Comment: well, don't bother sorting by timestamp on the inner SELECT. It will make no difference on final result, just an extra sort

Comment: what is the relation between `activity` and `action`?  Is it one to one, or many activity per action or many action per activity? Without FTS, you cannot avoid a full table scan, but you might be getting multiple scans of the same thing.

Comment: There is no `FULLTEXT` index involved.  Please change the title.

Comment: Please determine which of the subqueries is slower so we can focus on it.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  All versions have `FULLTEXT`.

Comment: Thanks guys so much. If you'd like to know I'm using Oxwall Newsfeed Plugin. One action can have multiple activities.

Comment: FULLTEXT is not working for some reason! I have noticed that when table has primary key auto increment FULLTEXT don't work! So y decided to skip it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my best guess.

Add an index to `activity.actionId`

It looks like you have multiple `activity`'s for each `action`. That means, you are searching the same action multiple times, and then, basically randomly, just using one of the `timeStamp` fields from the activities.  The only thing you are getting from activity table is the timestamp.

As it scans the activity table, it will jump all over the place reading from the action table, even reloading the same page multiple times. This kills performance.

Instead, have it scan the actions table and use an index on the activity table to get the timestamp.

Also, you should be able to simplify the query somewhat.

```
select  b.activityActionId,b.creatorFeedId,b.priority
 from
(SELECT action.id as activityActionId, 
NULL as creatorFeedId, 
(SELECT MAX(activity.timeStamp) FROM activity WHERE activity.actionid=action.id) as timeStamp, 
(action.data like '%you%')+(action.data like '%don%')+(action.data like '%see%')+(action.data like '%this%' )+(action.data like '%email%')+( action.data like '%your%' )+( action.data like '%inbox%' )+(action.data like '%within%' )+(action.data like '%minutes%' ) ... as priority
         FROM `action` 
         WHERE (    (action.data like '%you%')+(action.data like '%don%')+(action.data like '%see%')+(action.data like '%this%' )+(action.data like '%email%')+( action.data like '%your%' )+( action.data like '%inbox%' )+(action.data like '%within%' )+(action.data like '%minutes%' ) ...) > 0 AND action.id != "56"
union
        SELECT NULL as actionId, `actionId`, null as timeStamp, null as priority    
        FROM `activity`             
WHERE `activityType` = "create" and `userId` = "1" and `actionId` != "56"
  ) b
         ORDER BY priority desc, b.`timeStamp` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: in fact, if you add an index for `actionid, timeStamp` you can probably eliminate looking at the activity table at all during the scan.

Comment: Thanks so much appreciate it. Let me try out your suggestions!